# GammaLn NameSpace In C#

Tags: c#

I purchased the book Numerical Methods, Algorithms and Tools in C# by Waldemar Dos Passos.
On page 463, there is the method:

```
public static double FactorialLn(int n)
{
    if(n < 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Input value must be > 0");
    }    
    else
    {
        return GammaLn(n+1.0);
    }
}
```

I found the namespace where the function GammaLn resides: MicrosoftResearch.Infer.Maths
but Visual Studio 2010 does not recognize it and I was unable to find it in the .NET reference.
Please help me get the program to compile.
Thank you in advance.
I finally found the dource code of the GammaLn method itself here: http://seungwon.tistory.com/9
One does need nothing else when one possesses the very real thing, as Andrey correctly pointed out, but until then ...
I reproduce the method here for future reference, in case the site above stops from functioning.

```
/// <summary>
    /// http://seungwon.tistory.com/9
    /// GammaLn函数
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static double GammaLn(double x)
    {
        double result = 0.0;
        double d1 = -5.772156649015328605195174e-1;
        double[,] p1 = {{4.945235359296727046734888e0},{ 2.018112620856775083915565e2},
                       {2.290838373831346393026739e3},{ 1.131967205903380828685045e4},
                       {2.855724635671635335736389e4},{ 3.848496228443793359990269e4},
                       {2.637748787624195437963534e4},{ 7.225813979700288197698961e3}};

        double[,] q1 = {{6.748212550303777196073036e1},{ 1.113332393857199323513008e3},
                       {7.738757056935398733233834e3},{ 2.763987074403340708898585e4},
                       {5.499310206226157329794414e4},{ 6.161122180066002127833352e4},
                       {3.635127591501940507276287e4},{ 8.785536302431013170870835e3}};

        double d2 = 4.227843350984671393993777e-1;

        double[,] p2 = {{4.974607845568932035012064e0},{ 5.424138599891070494101986e2},
                       {1.550693864978364947665077e4},{ 1.847932904445632425417223e5},
                       {1.088204769468828767498470e6},{ 3.338152967987029735917223e6},
                       {5.106661678927352456275255e6},{ 3.074109054850539556250927e6}};

        double[,] q2 = {{1.830328399370592604055942e2},{ 7.765049321445005871323047e3},
                       {1.331903827966074194402448e5},{ 1.136705821321969608938755e6},
                       {5.267964117437946917577538e6},{ 1.346701454311101692290052e7},
                       {1.782736530353274213975932e7},{ 9.533095591844353613395747e6}};

        double d4 = 1.791759469228055000094023e0;

        double[,] p4 = {{1.474502166059939948905062e4},{ 2.426813369486704502836312e6},
                       {1.214755574045093227939592e8},{ 2.663432449630976949898078e9},
                       {2.940378956634553899906876e10},{ 1.702665737765398868392998e11},
                       {4.926125793377430887588120e11},{5.606251856223951465078242e11}};

        double[,] q4 = {{2.690530175870899333379843e3},{ 6.393885654300092398984238e5},
                       {4.135599930241388052042842e7},{ 1.120872109616147941376570e9},
                       {1.488613728678813811542398e10},{1.016803586272438228077304e11},
                       {3.417476345507377132798597e11},{ 4.463158187419713286462081e11}};

        double[,] c = {{-1.910444077728e-03},{ 8.4171387781295e-04},
                      {-5.952379913043012e-04},{ 7.93650793500350248e-04},
                      {-2.777777777777681622553e-03},{ 8.333333333333333331554247e-02},
                      { 5.7083835261e-03}};

        double eps = 2.2204e-016;

        if (x <= 0)
        {
            //报错！
        }
        else
        {
            double xden = 0.0;
            double xnum = 0.0;

            result = x;

            if (x > 0 && x <= eps)
            {
                result = -Math.Log(x);
            }
            else if ((x > eps) && (x <= 0.5))
            {
                double y = x;
                xden = 1;
                xnum = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    xnum = xnum * y + p1[i, 0];
                    xden = xden * y + q1[i, 0];
                }
                result = -Math.Log(y) + (y * (d1 + y * (xnum / xden)));
            }
            else if ((x > 0.5) && (x <= 0.6796875))
            {
                double xm1 = (x - 0.5) - 0.5;
                xden = 1;
                xnum = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    xnum = xnum * xm1 + p2[i, 0];
                    xden = xden * xm1 + q2[i, 0];
                }
                result = -Math.Log(x) + xm1 * (d2 + xm1 * (xnum / xden));
            }
            else if ((x > 0.6796875) && (x <= 1.5))
            {
                double xm1 = (x - 0.5) - 0.5;
                xden = 1;
                xnum = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    xnum = xnum * xm1 + p1[i, 0];
                    xden = xden * xm1 + q1[i, 0];
                }
                result = xm1 * (d1 + xm1 * (xnum / xden));
            }
            else if ((x > 1.5) && (x <= 4))
            {
                double xm2 = x - 2;
                xden = 1;
                xnum = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    xnum = xnum * xm2 + p2[i, 0];
                    xden = xden * xm2 + q2[i, 0];
                }
                result = xm2 * (d2 + xm2 * (xnum / xden));
            }
            else if ((x > 4) && (x <= 12))
            {
                double xm4 = x - 4;
                xden = -1;
                xnum = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    xnum = xnum * xm4 + p4[i, 0];
                    xden = xden * xm4 + q4[i, 0];
                }
                result = d4 + xm4 * (xnum / xden);
            }
            else if (x > 12)
            {
                double y = x;
                double r = c[6, 0];// 等于：double r = repmat(c[6, 0], 1)[0,0];
                double ysq = y * y;

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    r = r / ysq + c[i, 0];
                }
                r = r / y;
                double corr = Math.Log(y);
                double spi = 0.9189385332046727417803297;
                result = r + spi - 0.5 * corr + y * (corr - 1);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I **guess** GammaLn is another function defined somewhere before in the book. Nothing to do with MicrosoftResearch.infer.Maths! BTW Source code in a book throws System.Exception for an invalid argument? OMG!

Comment: Googling `MicrosoftResearch.Infer.Maths` brought me to [ThisPage](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/blogs/bayesianpca.aspx), it has a download link, if its not this, check the front of your book in the introduction to see what it requires

Comment: According to syntax `GammaLn` is method defined in this class somewhere else. So Adriano is right.

Comment: Also see http://books.google.com/books?id=oLOB2rvNegUC&lpg=PT729&ots=P2CGODZJhs&dq=%22Numerical%20Methods%2C%20Algorithms%20and%20Tools%20in%20C%23%22%20GammaLn&hl=nl&pg=PT727#v=onepage&q&f=false (sorry I can't see the page number but I'm sure you'll be able to find it in your hardcopy).